# Fine grained resource management in an async function?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

Using `@asyncio.coroutine` one can write a fine-grained resource manager for acquiring and releasing a shared resource (say a `Lock` or a global variable or database connection):

```py
@asyncio.coroutine
def resource_context(func: Callable[..., Awaitable]):
    print("acquire")
    for i in func().__await__():
        print("release")
        yield i
        print("acquire")
    print("release")
```

This fine grained resource management requires use of `yield` rather `yield from`. This is much finer grained than a context manager which would simply acquire once at the beginning and release once at the end. Whereas a context manager would hold the resource while our `func` waits, this finer grained releases the resource each time it is waiting.

But `@asyncio.coroutine` is deprecated as of Python 3.8. How can I achieve this functionality using the more modern `async def` coroutines?

Note I'm not looking for an async iterator or an async context manager: neither of those work for this use case. I'd like to be able to await arbitrary other async functions that are called inside `func` and release the resource when any of those callees awaits anything. That is, I'd like for the resource to be acquired inside `func` and any code it calls, but to be temporarily released while `func` yields control.

Comment: Can _what_ functionality be implemented exactly? It is not clear what you want to accomplish here. The term _"resource manager"_ is unclear as well (in the Python context). What resource? How do you want to manage it? You also talk about _"arbitrary async helpers"_ as if that is a defined term, and about _"releasing"_ that mysterious resource as though it is obvious what that means. To summarize, I would suggest you edit this post and use precise pre-defined terminology or at least define the terms you use to make it clear what you are talking about.

Comment: It may help others to understand the goal by providing a _usage_ example, i.e. a simple problem, showing how the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator helped to solved that problem, demonstrating how it **can not** be solved with the existing, non-deprecated tools (as you claimed), and then putting forward the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that works, but it's not pretty:

```py
class AwaitOne(typing.NamedTuple):
    future: asyncio.Future
    def __await__(self):
        yield self.future

async def resource_context(coro: typing.Awaitable):
    print("acquire")
    for future in coro.__await__():
        print("release")
        await AwaitOne(future)
        print("acquire")
    print("release")
```

What I think is going on here is that the new `await` syntax simulates not an old-style `yield` but rather an old style `yield from`. Now we need to yield from an iterable of futures, but we have only a single future. So let's wrap that in the `await` equivalent of a sequence of length one. This length-one container just needs an `__await__` method that yields its single future.

Comment: _How_ does that work? What does it do? In what way does this solve the problem? It may be obvious to you, what the goal is and what this code is supposed to do, but just dumping a code snippet into an answer without any explanation is not considered particularly [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).